# Problemas con type="number" HTML5

Tags: html

Tengo un formulario donde decidí usar el type="number" para el campo código postal estableciendo un valor mínimo y máximo pero cuando ingreso los datos con el teclado y no con las opciones de incrementar y disminuir me da un error como si el valor que estoy ingresando es mayor al que realmente es. Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

A continuación el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="feature-wrapper bg-success pt-5 pb-5 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
      <div class="wrapper wrapper--w790">
          <div class="card card-5">
            <h1 class="display-3" align="center">Titulo</h1>
              <div class="card-heading">
                  <h2 class="title">Subtitulo</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <form method="POST" action"">                                                      <div class="form-row m-b-55">
                          <div class="name">Código Postal</div>
                          <div class="value">
                              <div class="row row-space">
                                  <div class="col-2">
                                      <div class="input-group-desc">
                                          <input class="input--style-5" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" name="zipcode" required>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>                                        
                      <div align="center">
                          <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--green" type="submit" name="enviar" aling="center">Enviar</button>
                          <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="reset" aling="center">Cancelar</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Adicionalmente coloco el código de w3school porque aquí al parecer no funciona esa opción:** https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXA9QLFTTSE2

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir exactamente? ¿Que el código postal tenga un mínimo de 1 caracter y un máximo de 5? ¿Por qué necesitas que sea type="number"? Los códigos postales suelen ser tratados como string, ya que no vas a usarlos para hacer operaciones matemáticas entre ellos.

Comment: Ciertamente estaba pensado y ademas hay codigo postales que tienen letras así que mejor lo dejo como texto y ya, solo queria cuidar que realmente ingresaran un codigo postal

Comment: Efectivamente, los códigos postales varían mucho dependiendo del país, por lo que es un lío usar expresiones regulares para controlarlos. Si quisieras validar que efectivamente sea un código postal tendrías que identificar el país al que pertenece ese código y aplicarle una expresión regular que verifique expresamente los de ese país. Así que tienes complicado establecer restricciones como tipo de caracteres o longitud del código postal.